# How to hide ms access class objects in access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I know it's possible to hide Table, Query, Forms, etc from the Navigation Pane.

But is it possible to hide ms access class objects in access 2013 as shown below?

### Before Hidden:

[image: Before Hidden]

### After Hidden:

[image: After Hidden]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to hide individual Modules or Class Modules in the VBA Project Explorer. However, you can right-click on the project root and choose "<ProjectName> Properties..."

[image: Properties.png]

and then enable "Lock project for viewing" on the "Protection" tab:

[image]

That will protect the entire VBA project from prying eyes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I just want to hide it from other administrator, just like hiding one form or one query. Thanks anyway.